# Windows 10 OpenSSH config file not being read properly

Tags: windows, windows-10, openssh

I am currently trying to set-up my SSH at home to connect to the servers at my work. I am using OpenSSH from the latest Windows 10. However, I am having problems with the fact that OpenSSH seems to not be reading the config file I have in my ~/.ssh folder. Currently, my config file looks like this.

```
# Host 2
Host other.server.name.com
    Hostname other.server.name.com
    User my_name
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/private_key_2
    Port xx
    ProxyCommand ssh.exe xxx.xx.x.xxx -W %h:%p

# Host 1
Host xxx.xx.x.xxx
    Hostname xxx.xx.x.xxx
    User my_name
    IdentityFile  ~/.ssh/private_key_1
    Port xx
```

Those aren't the actual names of stuff (obviously) but it is set-up to proxy through Host 1 to get to Host 2.

Also, when in command prompt, I run `ssh-add -l' I get:

```
>ssh-add -l
2048 SHA256:j9VitpahZREpE30Ms+A5x2oyKNY+0c/QlIVSrplXDDM \Users\gakle/.ssh/private_key_1(RSA)
2048 SHA256:o740kUMt8QT/Po7m1s7LQ8DcvGxHOj0Hi0m96W9fPN4 \Users\gakle/.ssh/private_key_2(RSA)
```

I am not entirely sure what I have set-up incorrectly. Also, on the server side, my ~/.ssh folder is set to 755 and authorized_keys is set to 600. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: The issue you describe is well documented on the Github project for the OpenSSH Server feature you have installed.  What do you believe is the path to the configuration file?  Basically, Microsoft documentation is incomplete, people have found success using the same OpenSSH package from [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/packages/openssh/)

Comment: You mean the path to the ./ssh/config file, or are you referring to another configuration file?

Comment: Yes; The path to the ssh/config file.

Comment: It is in my Users folder, so C:/Users/[name]/.ssh/config

Comment: I am 90% sure the config file is by default is located `C:/ProgramData/ssh/` not the user profile.

Comment: `%PROGRAMDATA%/ssh/Logs` might also contain logs that provide insight into what configuration file is being read.

Answer (score 1):

Please provide the absolute path of your ssh key file in IdentityFile.

> e.g. IdentityFile C:/Users/raza/.ssh/xyz_rsa

Comment: Please use the comment section to ask questions. Also note that this is an old question and you'll likely wont get an answer.